# Passing Byte Array of dynamically generated content in memory as file format

Tags: c#, tfs

Using the CreateAttachment method for Microsoft Team Foundation Server:

```
ITestAttachment CreateAttachment(
    byte[] contents,
    int offset,
    int length
)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd778732.aspx

What is the proper method to create a byte array to pass as the contents in the above method?

```
test.txt
This is a text file containing some text
```

The user role given to the agent running this code does not have write permissions and cannot store a file locally, so everything must be created and passed to the `CreateAttachment()` method dynamically. Is there any way I can go about doing this?

Comment: string input = "This is a text file containing some text";
            byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

Comment: Is there a way that I can name the file using this formatting?

Comment: @Reed you have access to `google.com` I presume ? please take the time to do some basic research for all of this information is readily available at your finger tips, if you do a basic google search

Comment: @MethodMan Everything I've seen involving a file name also involves the System.IO library which I've stated I'm unable to write files.

Comment: What are you attaching to?

Comment: @jdweng I'm attempting to attach it to a TestRunResult in TFS. ITestCaseResult result = project.TestResults.Find(<id>, <runId>);string text = "this is some example text";
            byte[] byteText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            result.CreateAttachment(byteText, 0, byteText.Length);

Comment: You could use the description property.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.aspx

Comment: @jdweng I might be misunderstanding you, but adding it to the description wouldn't do what I'm trying to achieve, I need to attach multiple files including XMLs and TXTs of logs, etc.

Comment: You can create you own class that inherits the TestResults class and then add additional properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for your reference:

```
        TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http:/tfserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/"));
        ITestManagementService itms = ttpc.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
        ITestManagementTeamProject project = itms.GetTeamProject("EmptyTFVC");
        ITestCaseResult result = project.TestResults.Find(1, 100000);
        string contentstring = "This is test string for attachment.";
        byte[] conBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contentstring);
        ITestAttachment attachment = result.CreateAttachment(conBytes,0,conBytes.Length);
        attachment.Name = "test.txt";
        result.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        result.Save();
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for and is working great.